# Finding a CPU's Capacitive Load - Computer Architecture

Tags: power, capacitance

I'm new to computer architecture, and found a question similar to that on this site already with actually quoting the same text book. I'm struggling to figure out if the answer is 1.77Ghz or 3.55Ghz. Could someone people provide some explanation to what it might be?

```
You are asked to modify an old CPU which runs at 2GHz and design a new CPU with 55% less power
consumption. The use of a new technology helps to reduce the capacitive load in the new CPU by 40% and
the voltage by 35%. Calculate the clock frequency, which needs to be adopted by the new CPU such that
the power consumption of the new processor is reduced by 55%.
```

At first I thought it would be 3.55Ghz but then when I tried writing out the question, I noticed I could just cancel out the 2Ghz as it's the old frequency and it can be found on both the bottom and top of the equation (according to lecture notes). Appreicate any feedback!

Example found in notes:
[image]

Comment: Check the notes again.  Maybe post your prof's equation for power consumption as a function of capacitance, voltage, and speed.

Comment: Hey @TimWescott, added his example there now.

Comment: The new frequency is unknown so it isn't going to cancel out of your equation.

Comment: Wouldn't I just replace the Fold on the top and bottom with it and then cancel it out? @SpehroPefhany Sorry if it's a dumb question, just unsure about this one.

Comment: You're asked to calculate fnew. The example is not exactly the same as your question.

Comment: Oh I know, but I was wondering would I not be able to cancel it out as I have the Pnew, Cnew and Vnew, could I not just divide the Pnew/Cnew * Vnew^2 to get the Fnew?

Comment: Calculate fnew/fold.

Comment: The 'Fold" in that equation shows up in the expression "0.85 * Fold".  0.85 * Fold in that example is Fnew.  Since the prof used a 15% reduction for everything, it's the same story with capacitance and voltage.  I suggest you dig back further in your notes for the **original** equation, or that you look at your example equation and post your guess at the original equation here for us to comment on.

Comment: Hey @TimWescott that was the original one now sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't calculate the actual value of the capacitive load without knowing the voltage and power but we don't need to, knowing the ratios of old voltage to new voltage, old capacitive load to new capacitive load and old power to new power is enough.

So we have your equation for the power consumption of a CMOS chip (assuming that most load is dynamic)

$$P = \frac{1}{2}cv^2f $$

Lets write that out for both the old and new chips.

$$P_\mathrm{old} = \frac{1}{2}c_\mathrm{old}v_\mathrm{old}^2f_\mathrm{old} $$

$$P_\mathrm{new} = \frac{1}{2}c_\mathrm{new}v_\mathrm{new}^2f_\mathrm{new} $$

Now lets write out what we have been told.

$$f_\mathrm{old} = 2\times10^9$$

$$p_\mathrm{new} = 0.45p_\mathrm{old}$$

$$c_\mathrm{new} = 0.6c_\mathrm{old}$$

$$v_\mathrm{new} = 0.65v_\mathrm{old}$$

Sustitute

$$P_\mathrm{old} = \frac{1}{2}c_\mathrm{old}v_\mathrm{old}^2 2\times 10^9$$

$$0.45P_\mathrm{old} = \frac{1}{2}0.6c_\mathrm{old}(0.65v_\mathrm{old})^2f_\mathrm{new} $$

$$0.45\frac{1}{2}c_\mathrm{old}v_\mathrm{old}^2 2\times 10^9 = \frac{1}{2}0.6c_\mathrm{old}(0.65v_\mathrm{old})^2f_\mathrm{new} $$

Cancel

$$0.45 \times 2\times 10^9 = 0.6(0.65)^2f_\mathrm{new} $$

Calculate numbers

$$ f_\mathrm{new} \approx 3.55 \times 10^9$$